# Как задать стили элемента, когда на странице он представлен двумя соседями?

Tags: html, css

Например, на странице идёт: `<img><img>`

Как задать стили, которые бы применились к `<img>`,  когда это два соседа, и не применялись к одиночным `<img>`?

Comment: Никак, ждём CSS4 и не факт, что там будет такое. Используйте JS.

Answer (score 1):

Если варианта всего два: 1 `img` или 2 `img`, то можно с помощью конструкции `:last-child:first-child`.

В примере через `p`.

```css
p{
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 20px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
}

p:last-child:first-child {
   background-color: white;
   color: blue;
}
```

```html
Нас Два соседа
<div>
  <p>1</p>
  <p>2</p>
</div>

Нас Один
<div>
  <p>1</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Если изображения разделены каким-либо элементом (не текстом), то задачу можно решить используя псевдокласс [:has()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/:has). Но, перед применением, проверьте [поддержку браузерами](https://caniuse.com/css-has).

```css
img {
  margin: 5px;
  width: 100px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 5px #000;
}

img:has(+ img),
img + img {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 5px #f00;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/VxVNC.jpg" alt="yellow flower">
<span>ELEM</span>
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/A9VLC.jpg" alt="green forest">
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/oYG0R.jpg" alt="blue rose">
<span>ELEM</span>
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/MraLT.jpg" alt="red wall">
<span>ELEM</span>
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/A9VLC.jpg" alt="green forest">
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/oYG0R.jpg" alt="blue rose">
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/oYG0R.jpg" alt="blue rose">
```

Answer (score 0):

Решаемо даже в рамках всех нормальных браузеров и css3, без :has() и скриптов. Нужно только решить какой именно img нужно отлавливать.

```css
img {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin: 5px;
}


/* you need this: */

.wrapper img:nth-last-of-type(2) {
  background-color: pink;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <img/>
  <img/>
</div>
<hr>
<div class="wrapper">
  <img/>
  <span>*</span>
  <img/> *
  <span>*</span>
</div>
```